# How to get the number of search results in google using selenium?

Tags: java, selenium

I am trying to get the number of google search result using java and selenium.

```
String numberOfSearchResult = searchResults.getText().split(" ")[1];
```

I tried this line of code and is not working in different language browser.
For example, in chrome that is in english it's working but not on chrome in Japanese because the split gives me a text that is not a number.
Any way to solve this?

Thanks

Comment: Look at the locator and what it finds in both languages. My guess is that it's not pointing at the same element in both cases or you need to adjust your split.

Comment: Current, how do you initialize the element ? `WebElement searchResults = ?`